# Computing Euler Angles from Direction Cosines Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, analytic-geometry, triangles

My problem simply as the following:
Suppose we measured the orientation of a plane object with respect to a reference fame. (where the reference frame parallel to plane frame). The unit normal vector for plane is:

`[Vx;Vy;Vz] = [0.2585;0;0.966] --> 65 degrees around x-axis; 90 degree around y-axis and 15 degrees around z-axis`.

The Rotations are described by various means

- Direction Cosines Matrix (DCM)
- Euler Angles
- Quaternion
- Rodriquez parameters, Gibbs vector, etc.

Now, I'm using a software that just represent the orientation of the object using the three Euler Angles. My problem is how it possible to compute the three Euler Angles from the direction cosine vector given above?

Any Help Please.